# Spring activiti - how to complete a particular task when we have multiple requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I have the following bpm flow, where in the first user task - multiple users will log in and create a document. But in the second user task we have to Audit the same record and close it.

[image]

Question: If multiple users create the document using Data Entry task, then how the auditor or Activiti knows which task to be closed.

Please help me in understanding how activiti works in the above scenario.

Comment: Each data entry/ audit pair belongs to a different process instance, so your auditor will only act on a single document at a time. In order to select a given audit the common practice is to have an UI that looks like an email input box, from which he/she can pick a task.

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre - Thanks for the reply. Yes, as you said "auditor will only act on a single document at a time" - I agree but as I said we might have number of data entry tasks have created. So when the auditor have to check and confirm one by one - how can we relate particular flow with the task to complete the workflow.

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre - I got the solution for this. Thanks a lot for your reply. :)

Comment: Glad you figured out ! The API for looking up tasks for a given user/role is pretty straightforward in Activiti/Flowable.